# How to draw this LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to realize a LinearLayout in Android like this:

{ deleted image }

but I don't know how to do.

If I do:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="60dp" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp" >
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>    
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="80dp" 
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The second LinearLayout (on the right) is not shown. I think I would have to use a RelativeLayout, but how can I draw a similar LinearLayout?

This is the layout used for a ListItem in a ListView so every box has to have the same width (hence cannot use wrap_content for the 2 item_0 and item_1 layout wrapper.

Comment: and next question will be ... "why my ListView works so slowly" ... see my answer and read article

Comment: Could you source another image to replace the dead one in this question? Meantime I will try to get it closed (it can always be reopened if an image can be found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="60dp" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:layout_weight="70">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>    
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="80dp" 
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think it's preferable to do it with a RelativeLayout, it will be easier

Answer (score 2):

Try adding android:layout_weight="1" to your first child LinearLayout inside the top level LinearLayout (i.e. the one on the 5th line of your XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30dp">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" android:textColor="#ff0000">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="80dp" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#ff0000">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it will be better if you get rid of all nested LinearLayouts and made all this stuff in ONE RealativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

so more efficient way will be this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="60dp" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_2">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="18dp" android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_0" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_2">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```